# Azure Virtual Desktop (AVD) disconnecting clients

Tags: azure

We have an application published through AVD. It is running on a host pool of 5 VMs. It has been running for over a year with no issues. Today we started having users either get disconnected or not be able to connect. The log viewer shows several instances of terminal server faulting. This is a an example of the log entry we are seeing.

```
Faulting application name: svchost.exe_TermService, version: 10.0.17763.3346, time stamp: 0xb6a0daab
Faulting module name: RdpCoreCDV.dll, version: 10.0.25120.1001, time stamp: 0x41251cf2
Exception code: 0xc0000005
Fault offset: 0x00000000002b9ed0
Faulting process id: 0x1c7b8
Faulting application start time: 0x01d8c3c9f51424f0
Faulting application path: C:\Windows\System32\svchost.exe
Faulting module path: C:\Program Files\Microsoft RDInfra\StackSxS\1.0.2205.16200\RdpCoreCDV.dll
Report Id: 48904f40-3c25-4239-9577-0b192c509c80
Faulting package full name: 
Faulting package-relative application ID:
```

We have open RDP sessions directly to each of the 5 servers and all are experiencing the same issue. We have also rebooted each server. Nothing seems to help. This pool is powered off every night and then restarted the next morning.
We have opened a support ticket with Microsoft but have had very little help so far.
Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

We seemed to have solved the problem by upgrading the avd agent to the latest version on the session host servers. We are not positive that was the issue but have not had the problem since doing that. The upgrade was to version 1.0.5388.1701. I have not been able to find any release notes for this version so I don't know if there was a specific fix related to this in that version.